# Getting the value of array through loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this type of array and i want to get the values of cid,totalDistance , etc...

And there can be multiple **cid, totalDistance , etc** , so how can i show the values in a tabular format using loop ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cid] => 6362165
            [totalDistance] => 13.727617595403
            [totalTrips] => 17
            [avgSpeed] => 4.1792097792906
            [avgSt] => 1446460214749
            [avgEt] => 1446460795802
            [avgScore] => 56
            [tripIds] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 230529
                    [1] => 230531
                    [2] => 230527
                    [3] => 230528
                    [4] => 230524
                    [5] => 230526
                    [6] => 230520
                    [7] => 230521
                    [8] => 230522
                    [9] => 230523
                    [10] => 230525
                    [11] => 230530
                    [12] => 230532
                    [13] => 230533
                    [14] => 230534
                    [15] => 230535
                    [16] => 230536
                )

        )
```

**In This Format**

```
cid  totalDistance  totalTrips  avgspeed  avgSt  avgEt  avgScore  tripIds

val1     val2         val3        val4    val5    val6     val7     val8
```

These values can be more depending on the array containing values.

Comment: Please edit your question tags to include the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if i understand the question right. But as i understand just with a normal `foreach` loop.

PHP:

```
$routes = array(
array(
    'cid'               => 1,
    'totalDistance'     => 13.727617595403,
    'totalTrips'        => 17,
    'avgSpeed'          => 4.1792097792906,
    'avgSt'             => 1446460214749,
    'avgEt'             => 1446460795802,
    'avgScore'          => 56,
    'tripIds'           => array(

    ),
),
array(
    'cid'               => 2,
    'totalDistance'     => 13.727617595403,
    'totalTrips'        => 17,
    'avgSpeed'          => 4.1792097792906,
    'avgSt'             => 1446460214749,
    'avgEt'             => 1446460795802,
    'avgScore'          => 56,
    'tripIds'           => array(

    ),
));
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>cid</td>
    <td>totalDistance</td>
    <td>totalTrips</td>
    <td>avgSpeed</td>
    <td>avgSt</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($routes as $route): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $route['cid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $route['totalDistance']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $route['totalTrips']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $route['avgSpeed']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $route['avgSt']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Mybe you should think to use an object and not an array, but thats your choice

Comment: You skip the 'multi-dimensional' part from his/her question's title.